# How can Record Macro create code in New Module instead of Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using "Record Macro" function in Excel 2010. In VB Editor generated code is placed in Sub Macro1() inside "Module1". Every next record is placed in "Module1" under Sub Macro2().

How can I get **new generated code in new "Module2"** instead of "Module1" or new Workbook?

Thank you

Comment: Just create a new module `Module2` and copy paste the `Macro2()` there after recording. Excel will always record the macros in one module. Actually it is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Of course I can copy text but that's not the point. I saw somewhere that this option is possible but I cant find it on internet.

Comment: The question actually is why would you want to do that? What is the purpose of that? After recording a macro you should refine it anyway and you should rename the module from `Module1` to something meaningful. So actually I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save and close the workbook, then re-open it.

The next time you use Record Macro, it will default to Module2.

Comment: I knew it, it can be done! thank you @MarkFitzgerald